# how to generate python unittesting report in XML format to summarize passed and failed test cases

Tags: python, unit-testing

I am automating test cases in python and results are redirected to text file by default for unittest. I want result to be generated in XML format so that I can easily track passed and failed test cases. Please suggest.

Answer (score 1):

There is a seperate package called [unittest-xml-reporting](https://github.com/danielfm/unittest-xml-reporting)

To use it add this to your unit test

```
import xmlrunner
```

Then pass the XMLRunner to unittest like this:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main(testRunner=xmlrunner.XMLTestRunner(output='test-reports'))
```